# How do I really get the current revision in SVN?

Tags: svn

I made a simple script to have my current revision copied to clipboard. At least that's what I thought I did after I used this post: [Current Subversion revision command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991526/current-subversion-revision-command)

[image]

But as you can see in the image, what the command gives is not the revision number of the current branch at all. So how do I really get the revision number of the branch via a command?

Comment: a lot of the confusion comes from the fact that after you committed a new revision, your work area will still reside on the old revision number, whereas the new revision number will only be in your repository, hence the different numbers when you use `svnversion`. Do a `svn update` after `svn commit` and `svnversion` is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the actual command that I'm using and that is the only one that works for me to get current revision is this one:

```
svn info --revision HEAD --show-item last-changed-revision
```

Comment: I think there's a typo. Shouldn't the command be: `svn info --revision HEAD --show-item last-changed-revision`

Comment: I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr:

Use the `COMMITTED` alias instead of `HEAD`

#### Details:

The most direct way to get the revision at the "tip" of the current branch is to use the `COMMITTED` alias instead of `HEAD` (it's amazing that I wasn't aware of the `COMMITTED` alias for so long).

Git uses `HEAD` to refer to the tip of the current branch.

Subversion uses `HEAD` to refer to the tip of the *entire* repository - *not* the current branch for the workspace.  Subversion uses the `COMMITTED` alias for that.

`svn info` shows both pieces of information:

```
        C:>svn info
        Path: .
        Working Copy Root Path: --elided--
        URL: svn:--elided--
        Relative URL: ^--elided--
        Repository Root: svn:--elided--
        Repository UUID: dcba06d3-f740-481d-b6cf-80debfe3ba96
1) ---> Revision: 40018
        Node Kind: directory
        Schedule: normal
        Last Changed Author: mike
2) ---> Last Changed Rev: 40013
        Last Changed Date: 2022-06-15 08:06:48 -0700 (Wed, 15 Jun 2022)
```

- #1 is the tip of the repository
- #2 is the tip of the current workspace's branch

If you just want the commit ID:

```
C:>svn info -r HEAD --show-item revision
40018

C:>svn info -r COMMITTED --show-item revision
40013
```

And if you want the log information, note that asking for `HEAD` will give you nothing (unless `HEAD` == `COMMITTED`).   Asking for `COMMITTED` will show exactly what you want:

```
C:>svn log -r HEAD
------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:>svn log -r COMMITTED
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r40013 | mike | 2022-06-15 08:06:48 -0700 (Wed, 15 Jun 2022) | 17 lines

    -- remainder of log message elided --

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a target for `svn info` then it defaults to '.' which is gonna be your working copy path.

Also from `svn help info`:

> TARGET may be either a working-copy path or a URL.  If specified,
>   REV   determines in which revision the target is first looked up; the
>   default   is HEAD for a URL or BASE for a WC path.

This means, if you want the HEAD revision then you have to specify the URL of your repository:

`svn info URL-of-repo --show-item revision`

Note that this is only how svn info works by default, you can always specify your own revision argument:

```
svn info --revision HEAD --show-item revision
```

On the other hand you can also use `svn status -u` to get the HEAD revision like so:

```
svn status -u | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

[image: Here's the result of these commands on my machine]

[image]

Comment: Neither of these works, it returns different revision than what I see in tortoise git.

Comment: Tortoise git? Also if they return a different revision than what you need, then I probably misunderstood the question. By current revision do you mean the HEAD revision or something else?

Comment: I want the revision number that is highligted, and that's the one that I pass to testers to fetch the commit that I just created. My current workflow is commit, then go to SVN Log and select "Copy -> Revisions". I wanted to speed that up.

Comment: I found that this works: `--revision HEAD --show-item last-changed-revision` But why this and not the others? Also `svnversion` sometimes returns two colon separated values. When it returns two, the second one is correct, but sometimes it just returns one that's wrong.

Comment: Well, as you can see on my screenshots, these commands do return the highlighted revision number on my machine and repository. There is a subtle difference between revision and last-changed-revision, sometimes they are the same, sometimes they are different. The revision number is the revision at which your file is synced up with the repository. The last-changed-revision is the revision during which the file was actually changed.

Comment: I feel like that's the difference in the result of svnversion too. When it gives 2 values, it actually gives you "revision:last-changed-revision", but when they are the same it only gives one.